# Bash: How to capture output of an "inner" tee in WSL

Tags: bash, variables, stream, pipe, tee

Currently, I am using the following (working) command in order to compress and encrypt some folders:

```bash
backup_folders "${srcFolders}" - $@ | encrypt > "${targetFile}"
```

`backup_folders` and `encrypt` are self-written Bash functions doing what their name says. `backup_folders` will create a tar.gz archive and write it to `stdout` in order to pipe it to further processing steps like `encrypt` above.

Now I would like to know the date of the newest file in the archive stream. To accomplish this, I added the following function:

```bash
get_newest_content() {
  local newestDate=$(tar --list --verbose --xz --full-time | awk '{ print $4 $5}' | sort -r | head -1)
  >&2 echo "Newest date of archive: ${newestDate}"
}
```

Then I updated my command from above to include this function like this:

```bash
backup_folders "${srcFolders}" - $@ | tee >(get_newest_content) | encrypt > "${targetFile}"
```

This is also working insofar as that the newest date is correctly determined and printed out (ignoring some formatting issues for now). But I would rather like to have this information contained in a variable. Thus, I need to capture the output of the function tee'd in the inner pipe.

I have tried the solutions mentioned here on SO and also [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/command-output-to-variable), all pointing towards writing the output from `get_newest_content` to another stream, e. g. like this (I tried multiple variations):

```bash
{ date=$(backup_folders "${srcFolders}" - $@ | tee >(get_newest_content) | encrypt > "${targetFile}"); } 2>&1
```

Unfortunately, I did not succeed, `date` is always empty or any value I initialized it with for testing.

As I am working under WSL (at least I guess, this is the reason...), I don't have `/dev/fd/3` and higher available. (Just `0`, `1`, `2` and `255`). I tried with `255` as well, but did not succeed.

Not being a very experienced Bash developer, I would like to kindly ask for help now. Probably, the solution is quite simple and the problem is sitting in front of the monitor. ^^

Comment: Aside: Unquoted `$@` acts exactly like `$*`; you need to write it as `"$@"` _with the quotes_ to get the behavior that makes `$@` special.

Comment: As for `/dev/fd/3`, it exists _only when you actually open a FD 3_. So if you put a `3>&1` on the outside, then you can use `/dev/fd/3` on the inside.

Comment: ...that said, capturing content from a deeply nested subshell is tricky, and it's often the easiest approach to use a temporary file for the purpose. (Typically on modern systems TMPDIR is stored on tmpfs, which is in-memory, so you're not churning actual disks); use `mktemp` to ensure your file has a unique name and isn't prone to timing/collision/symlink attacks and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, @CharlesDuffy! I'll give it another try opening FD 3 first. Anyway, I had also thought about using a temp file, but considered it rather nasty / inelegant. But as you said (and I'm glad you did and there is possibly no so easy solution I have just overseen), there might not be a better way and I will also take in into account again as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
date=$({ backup_folders "${srcFolders}" - $@ | tee >(get_newest_content >&3) | encrypt > "${targetFile}";} 3>&1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I feel a little embarrassed... I could swear I had tried this one before reading and trying out all the other stuff...